# Finding records where ID matches but other value does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The education department at my job is wanting some reports pulled from their online scholarship application, but before I can pull them I need to clean up the data. One thing they need is a list of any student who has changed degrees. Currently in the table that contains the degree information I have:

SchoolYearID, StudentID, InstID, Degree, Major, Minor, IsCurrent, OtherSchool, OtherSchoolHours, DateCreated, and InstStudentID.

How this app was built, the SchoolYearID is the primary Key, student ID is assigned to a student on signup, InstID is the ID given to the university. In the app itself, a student can select that they are going for a Masters degree plan, but then on the next page choose that they're a Freshmen. Inevitably I'll change this to be conditional, but for right now there are just a lot of students who have put the wrong degree plan down so we need to go in and change them.

The thing I can't figure out is how to select the individual student ID's as well as the Degree plan, but show ONLY the students whose degree has changed from one school year to another.

Edit: 
The SchoolYearID is just a number assigned to each application as it is created, it doesn't really have anything to do with the calendar year. A new SchoolYearID is generated for every new application, and students can apply for 3 different semesters (spring, summer, fall) so one student could have 3 different SchoolYearID's from the same calendar year.

So like

```
    SELECT *
    FROM CpnServicePortal.dbo.SchoolEnrollment
```

will return a result like

```
    SchoolYearID  StudentID  InstID  Degree  DegreeOther ...
    55            12         3232    M.B.A   NULL
    56            13         3235    Other   NULL
    60            20         3426    A.S.    NULL
```

And what I'm trying to come up with is

```
    SchoolYearID  StudentID  InstID  Degree  DegreeOther ...
    55            12         3232    M.B.A   NULL
    123           12         3232    A.S.    NULL
    60            20         3426    A.S.    NULL
    728           20         3426    B.S.    NULL
```

Where the studentID is matched (and if possible the InstID matches as well) but the Degree fields do not match.

Comment: Post some examples of the data, what you have so far and what your desired results are/

Comment: schoolYearID doesn't seem like a primary key

Comment: Please add a suscint example of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out which students had more than one degree, here's one option using `exists` with `max` and `min`:

```
select studentid, degree
from SchoolEnrollment s
where exists (
    select 1
    from SchoolEnrollment s2
    where s.studentid = s2.studentid
    group by studentid
    having max(degree) != min(degree)
)
```

I'm not sure how you define a different year though as I'm not seeing a `yearid` column.

Comment: he specifically said last year vs this year. Not at any time.

Comment: @KeithL I don't see a year column.  He mentions the `schoolyearid` is the primary key.  In your solution that won't work or only 1 student could sign up per year :)  I interpreted it differently than you: `from one school year to another`...

Comment: They did ask me just for this past year, but I can't say that they wouldnt want to know from the beginning of time at some point. @sgeddes your query is showing me everyone even if they didn't change degree programs. I can sift through them and find the records where the studentID matches, but honestly I'd rather not have to do that :/

Comment: @NathanHawkins Made a small mistake.  Here's a demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/msWqk81WBjdnAgA3pj8f8e/0

Comment: @NathanHawkins Still not sure what defines a `year` though?

Comment: @sgeddes in this case i guess the year is defined by DateCreated? At this point, if I'm able to find where any student changed degrees ever, I can narrow it down with that column

Comment: @NathanHawkins Did you run that demo?  I put your sample data in the fiddle and if you click "Run", it should return your expected results.

Comment: Yes, your demo worked great. Can it be re-purposed for a similar query in a different table? Like, where SemesterID matches but GradeID does not?

Comment: @NathanHawkins Definitely!  Just play around with it.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

this is classic year over year analysis:

I am assuming that each student has one record per year. You have to modify to get the records you want to compare.

```
declare @CY int = 2018;

;with lastYear as
(
   select *
   from [Table]
   where SchoolYearID=@cy-1
)

select cy.*
from [table] cy
    join lastYear on lastYear.StudentID = cy.StudentID
where schoolYearID=@CY
    and lastYear.Degree <> cy.Degree
```

Comment: when I tried your query, I would get an ambiguous column name error on WHERE SchoolYearID = @CY and when I try to define the table it wont allow me to bind them

Comment: Where cy.schoolyearid =@cy

Comment: Ambiguous column means that the column is in both ur table and the cte